# How do I embed a video url in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an object called News.
It has an attribute called embedded video html.

> this.news.embeddedVideoHtml = 'some iframe tag with video url'

How do I display this video in my html?

I have tried in this my component html

```
<div>
{{news.embeddedVideoHtml}}
</div>
```

But, this straight-up displays the html which is the iframe tag instead of rendering the video.

I tried innerHtml after reading a comment here. But, that did not work here as well.

```
<div [innerHtml]="news.embeddedVideoHtml">

</div>
```

Comment: Use `innerHTML` binding https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#one-time-string-initialization

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="video">
    <video controls #videoPlayer>
        <source src="{{videoSource}}" type="video/mp4" />
        Browser not supported
    </video>
</div>
```

or use some specific library that give you more control over it. There are a lot of examples.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-video

https://github.com/videogular/videogular2

http://www.videogular.com/

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using innerhtml but had to sanitize the url before being used it in innerhtml.
This is my HTML

```
<div [innerHtml]="sanitizeVideoUrl()">
```

This is my component ts.

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }
sanitizeVideoUrl() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.news.embeddedVideoHtml)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: you have sanitized in the backend and trust the html.

You also have the option to add a pipe.

blah.component.html

```
<div [innerHTML]="(news$ | async)?.embeddedVideoHtml | trustHtml">
</div>
```

TrustHtmlPipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'trustHtml',
})
export class TrustHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }
  public transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value)
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
...
import { TrustHtmlPipe } from './pipes/TrustHtmlPipe';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    TrustHtmlPipe],
...
```